# ng-controller with ng-repeat, where is the magic?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

main.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table ng-controller="RecordCtrl" ng-repeat="record in records">
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Team</th>
          <td>{{ record.team }}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.records = [
        { name: 'Alessandro Del Piero', team: 'Italy' },
        { name: 'Rui Costa', team: 'Portugal' },
    ];
}

function RecordCtrl($scope) {
    // I don't see here the "record" property
   console.log($scope);

   // I thought this would show undefined
   // ($scope.$parent.record exists, but not $scope.record)
   console.log($scope.record);
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4620/

Has recordController $scope "record" property or it inherits from the parent scope? I'm quite confuse...

Comment: The RecordCtrl scope is a children of MainCtrl scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inheritance, not magic: `$scope.$parent` is actually a prototype of `$scope`:

```
$scope.$parent === $scope.__proto__ // true
```

Quoting [**the doc**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its
>   parent scope.

Since JS will go up the prototype chain of `$scope` object when looking for a specific property not found on it directly, it'll collect the one set on `$scope.$parent`.